# If the int number close to the answer number it gives me a message in swift?

Tags: swift, if-statement, random, integer

I am trying to code a function that can give me a message when two int numbers get close.
Like:

```
static let too_low_number = "The number is too low."
static let low_number = "The number is low."
static let too_high_number = "The number is too high."
static let high_number = "The number is high."

var closemove = 10
var appanswer = Int.random(in: 1...100)
var playeranswer = 0
```

if `playeranswer` gets 10 int close to `appanswer` then it gives a message. Get 10 int close but less-than `appanswer` then it gives me `low_number` and Get bigger distance than 10 int but less-than `appanswer` then it gives me `too_low_number`.

same as getting 10 int close but greater-than `appanswer` then it gives me `high_number` and Get bigger distance than 10 int but greater-than `appanswer` then it gives me `too_high_number`.

Comment: Use switch/case or if/else to test from lowest number to bigger number

Answer (score 1):

You can check the difference between the player and the correct answer using `switch` with intervals for this. Here is a solution using `switch` in a computed property.

Please follow swift naming conventions of variables by using snake case, I took the liberty to rename all the variables in my code

```
var result: String {
    switch playerAnswer - appAnswer {
    case -closeMove..<0:
        return lowNumber
    case ..<(-closeMove):
        return tooLowNumber
    case 1...closeMove:
        return highNumber
    case (closeMove + 1)...:
        return tooHighNumber
    default:
        return "Right answer"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I code a function:

```
func result()-> String{
            var takeEx = 0
            if (getplayer < setApp) {
               takeEx = setApp - getplayer
                if (takeEx < 10) {
                    return low_number
                } else {
                    return too_low_number
                }
            } else if (getplayer > setApp){
                takeEx = getplayer - setApp
                if (takeEx < 10) {
                    return high_number 
                } else {
                    return too_high_number
                }
            } else if (getplayer == setApp){
                return congratulation
            }
        }
}
```